# Automatically choose between different options depending on which one produces the least badness

Tags: line-breaking

Is there a way in TeX (preferably plain XeTeX, but other engines are fine) to automatically choose between different options (e.g. between "and" and "&") so that the badness of a paragraph is minimal?

For example, for a small hsize, the following is fine

```
| I read a book by Smith & John. |
```

But if we increase the value of hsize, we have to add space:

```
| I read a book  by Smith &  John. |
```

So we prefer to use the other variant:

```
| I read a book by Smith and John. |
```

If I remember correctly, the first printers used this kind of trick to avoid line breaks.

Comment: my naive a priori is that there is no built-in such feature but at macro level you can probably do using `\pdfsavepos` based approach  (package tikzmark may provided high level approach), in controlled situations, where you know the exact textwidth etc.. However luatex looks like engine of choice for such things.

Comment: however in my comment the "badness" is only your manual measurement of where on the line you are and how far from right margin etc... it is not internally computed TeX one, for which no macro level access exists.